# CodeIgniter HMVC extends MX_Controller, unable to use get_instance properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have a controller in /application/core

**/application/core/CMS_Controller.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Controller.php";

class CMS_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show_something() {
        echo "something shown";
    }
}
```

I have another controller in a module (/modules/my_module/controllers/controller.php) which extended from CMS_Controller

**/modules/my_module/controllers/controller.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller extends CMS_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('view');
    }
}
```

And, in view.php (/modules/my_module/views/view.php) I do this:
**/modules/my_module/views/view.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 $ci =& get_instance();
 echo $ci->show_something();
?>
```

And I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI::show_something() in
>   /home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/modules/my_module/views/view.php on
>   line 3

It will works if I don’t use MX_Controller and using CI_Controller instead:
**/application/core/CMS_Controller.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Controller.php";

class CMS_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show_something() {
        echo "something shown";
    }
}
```

Anybody know what’s wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In application/third_party/MX/Controller.php
at the end of the constructor (after line 54)
i added

```
/* allow CI_Controller to reference MX_Controller */
CI::$APP->controller = $this;
```

if you look at the code $this refers to the current class which is MX_Controller and CI::$APP refers to the CI_controller (look at the MX/Base.php file)

so now its simple...
to get the reference to CI_Controller
we will do (as per normal)

```
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
```

and to get reference to MX_Controller we will do

```
    $this->CI =& get_instance()->controller;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, found that post and it made my website work, give it a try maybe?

"You don’t need to extend MX_Controller unless you are planning on running a controller within another controller. In alot of cases the code be put into a library. Otherwise, your controller should just extend MY_Controller."

Found here:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/179478/

Answer (score 0):

for me you don't need to get the instance so my try would be this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 echo $this->show_something();
?>
```

instead of

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 $ci =& get_instance();
 echo $ci->show_something();
?>
```

anyway it is good practice to set own libraries and do somenthing like:

```
$this->load->library('foo_lib');
$this->foo_lib->show_somenthing();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The script is on the view. I don't think that view can recognize $this. Right now I still have something else to do. But I'll comfirm the result later.